# Is a line, that's contained in a plane, parallel to it?

Tags: geometry, intuition, plane-geometry

Have got into a pretty heated debate with a friend, and looking online there's lacking proof
[Line contained in a plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S30uM.png)

Is a line that is contained within a plane, considered parallel to it? By my understanding it is parallel , if at all points the line has equal distance to the plane, which in this case is always 0, but they are  debating that it intersects the plane at infinitely many points, so it cannot be considered parallel, is there some mathematical proof that would prove or disprove either statement?

I see there is heated debate online about whether a line that matches another line is parallel to it and I'm wondering if there's a clean answer about this.

Comment: A line is parallel to plane if the normal of the plane is perpendicular to the line.

Comment: [Definition from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_(geometry)) seems to say no; from the first definition "parallel lines are lines in a plane which do not meet", and the plane and line has to "keep a fixed minimum distance".

Comment: @peterwhy Actually, Wikipedia does not say anything useful pertaining to OP's question. The 3rd sentence of the page you referenced says, "A line and a plane... in three-dimensional Euclidean space that do not share a point are... said to be parallel." However, this says nothing about a line and a plane that do share a point i.e. a line in a plane.

Comment: I would prefer "strict parallel" in the case that there is no common point since a better decription in the given case would be "lies in". In the same way I would speak of "identical lines" or "strict parallel lines".

Comment: I do not know whether there is a convention. If so, the debate is quite pointless. If not, the debate is similar fruitless as the debate whether $0$ belongs to the natural numbers. I remember the completely nonsencical millenium debate.

Comment: This kind of confusion is why real mathematicians use the terms "orthogonal", "linearly dependent", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about planes and lines in $\mathbb{R^3}$. If so, then all planes in are defined by a normal vector and a point, while all lines are defined by a direction vector and a point. It follows that some line will be parallel to some plane if that line's direction vector is perpendicular to that plane's normal vector, which reduces to checking their dot product.

P.S. This is just a preliminary answer. Do let me know if you require a more in-depth one and I will write it for you.

P.P.S Welcome to Math SE! If this answer has helped clear your doubts, do give it an upvote and the tick!

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely a question of convention. I'd say yes, because I like "parallelness" to be an equivalence relation, but it frankly does not matter in the slightest, providing you're clear about how you are using the word.

Comment: If a plane is parallel to two different lines, it doesn't follow that those lines are parallel to each other. So no equivalence relation here.

Comment: @TonyK Sorry, I should have been clearer: I like it to be an equivalence relation on surfaces of each dimension. That means allowing a line to be parallel to itself, at which point it is strange and inconsistent to not allow a line contained in a plane.

Comment: Yes, if your definition of 'parallel' implies that a line is parallel to itself, then for consistency a plane should be parallel to all lines contained in it. But most definitions of 'parallel' would say that a line is not parallel to itself, and we're back where we started. (I agree with you that a line should be considered as parallel to itself, but it doesn't seem to be generally accepted.)

Comment: If two lines are parallel to each other, it would be strange for a plane to be parallel to one line but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

In Euclidean space for two lines to be parallel they must never intersect. Since a line in a plane intersects the plane it cannot be parallel to it. Note that the lack of intersection is necessary but not sufficient in higher dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of opinion and convention, and one definition may be more useful than another definition for some purposes. This is common
in mathematics.

One definition of parallel lines in
a Euclidean plane is that they are equidistant from each other. This
breaks down in the context of the elliptic or hyperbolic plane and
it depends on a distance metric. Perhaps a better definition is that
they do not intersect. Again, this breaks down in the context of the
elliptic or hyperbolic plane. However, in the context of the projective
plane, this must be modified to state that parallel lines intersect
only at one point at infinity.

Moving up to three dimensional space, there is the concept of skew lines which don't intersect each other, and are not parallel since they are
not in the same plane. Introducing a plane at infinity, the definition
of parallel lines is the same as in a fixed plane. That is, they only intersect at one point at infinity. Any plane intersects the plane at
infinity in a line at infinity. Two parallel planes only intersect at
the same line at infinity.

It now makes sense that each line in a fixed plane intersects the same
line at infinity as the fixed plane does and exactly at one point.
This also holds for each line in a plane parallel to the fixed plane.
Thus, there are good reasons to consider every line in a plane to be
parallel to that plane.

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw my hat into the ring.

I certainly agree that it is a matter of convention.

However, it is also reasonable to presume that 3 dimensional Geometry is (in effect) an extension of 2 dimensional Geometry.

In 2 dimensional Geometry, I have never heard of the specification that a line is parallel to itself.  This (inconclusively) suggests that in 3 dimensional Geometry, a line can not be considered parallel to the plane that contains the line.

---

This is where the fun starts.  Normally, definitions, like the concept of parallel lines in 2 dimensional Geometry, are created in order to facilitate solving problems.  So, a hidden issue is the question of **why** the concept, in 3 dimensional Geometry, of a line being parallel to a plane, was created in the first place.

That is, what math problems is the definition designed to help solve.  Having identified these problems, you would then ask which convention facilitates solving these problems, whatever they are.